Use of const keyword with array pointers in C
In the 9th edition of Deitel's book C. How to program (chap. 7), a function is declared as
void bubbleSort(int * const array, size_t size)

and in the text it's specified that "function bubbleSort's header declares array as int * const array rather than int array[] to indicate that bubbleSort receives a one-dimensional array argument. Again, these notations are interchangeable; however, array notation generally is preferred for readability".
Since "array names are constant pointers to the array's first element" (quoting from the same chapter), and since a constant pointer to a non-constant data is defined (for example) with int * const myPtr, it makes sense that array as int * const array is equivalent to the more compact array notation when dealing with arrays.
However, at the beginning of the same chapter on pointers, the authors states that "When the compiler encounters a function parameter for a one-dimensional array of the form int b[], the compiler converts the parameter to the pointer notation int *b. The two forms are interchangeable".
So, according to the authors, both int * const array and int *array are equivalent to int array[]. Why add the const keyword if they're array names, and thus by defintion constant pointers to the array's first element? Or is this not true when arrays are passed to a function?


So, according to the authors, both int * const array and int *array
are equivalent to int array[].

Partially.

void foo(int array[]) and void foo(int *array) mean exactly the same
int * const array is something different: array is const pointer to int

The position of the const matters:

const int *array;  - array is a pointer to const int
int * const array; - array is a const pointer to int
const int * const array; - array is a const pointer to const int


Since array names are constant pointers to the first element of the
array,

No, they are not. Arrays decay to pointers to its first element when used in expressions or as function parameters. But not const pointers
Conclusion:
void foo(int array[])
void foo(int *array)

do the same
These ones:
void foo(int array[])
void foo(int *const array)

Do not as the parameter has a different type.


Since array names are constant pointers to the first element of the array…

This is false. An array is often converted to a pointer to its first element (but not always), and this may lead students to think of an array as a pointer, but it is not. There are important differences. sizeof array for an array and sizeof p for a pointer are different things and cannot be used interchangeably. An array is not converted to a pointer when it is the operand of sizeof, is the operand of a typeof operator, is the operand of unary &, or is a string literal used to initialize an array.

"When the compiler encounters a function parameter for a one-dimensional array of the form int b[], the compiler converts the parameter to the pointer notation int *b. The two forms are interchangeable".

This is a misstatement by the authors in two regards. First, this change of an array parameter to a pointer parameter is called an adjustment, not a conversion. This is because “conversions” in C refers to operations on values, but this is a change in the type of a function, not a conversion of values. Second, the adjustment is performed in the compiler’s internal representation of the function. It is not an adjustment the notation used in the source code. The compiler changes its internal data structures to record that the parameter is a pointer. It is unlikely a compiler would actually use the notation int b[] or int *b to record this information.

So, according to the authors, both int * const array and int *array are equivalent to int array[].

Your statement “Since array names are constant pointers…” was outside quotes, so you did not attribute it to the authors. The text you quoted did not say array names are constant pointers, and I doubt the book says that anywhere. If it does, you should quote that passage.
The quoted text does say “these notations are interchangeable,” but that is only in the context of a function parameter declaration, and it means a declaration of an array will be adjusted to be a declaration of a parameter. That is different from saying an array is equivalent to a constant pointer.
When the adjustment of an array parameter to a pointer parameter is performed, const is not added. Inside the body of a function declared with void foo(size_t size, int array[]), the type of array is int *, and it may be changed. array += 1 would change array to point to the next element in the array, and that is valid fully-defined C code (provided array was not already pointing to the end of the array).
An array parameter can be declared with const by putting const inside the brackets: int array[const]. Then this parameter declaration will be adjusted to declare a const pointer to int.

When describing what a constant pointer to a non-constant data is, the book explicitly says that "This [type of pointer: a constant pointer to a non-constant data] is the default for an array name, which is a constant pointer to the array's first element"; I've modified the question to include the exact same words from the book

@Pinuz: Okay, the book is wrong. An array name is not a constant pointer to the array’s first element.

"An array is not converted ..." --> perhaps add alignof.

@chux: alignof can only be applied to a type, not to an expression. C 2011 mistakenly included _Alignof in the list of array conversion exceptions. C 2018 corrected that. alignof (array) is a constraint violation. You could have alignof (typeof (array)), and then the typeof exception applies.

Both Deitel's phrasing and your understanding are a bit muddled.
First of all, let's talk about what
int * const array

actually does -- it will trigger a diagnostic if you attempt to write to array (changing it to point to something else).  It allows you to write
array[i] = some_int_value;

while disallowing
array = some_pointer_value;

IOW, it prevents you from accidentally clobbering your array pointer in the body of the function.  Doing so won't affect the pointed-to array, but it won't be ideal for your function working correctly.
However, it is not equivalent to
int array[]

which is "adjusted" to
int *array

not
int * const array

The equivalent parameter declaration using array notation would actually be
int array[const]

Array names are not pointers; when you declare an array as
int arr[SOME_SIZE];

this is what you get in memory (addresses are for illustration only and don't reflect any real platform):
               +---+
0x8000    arr: |   | arr[0]
               +---+
0x8004         |   | arr[1]
               +---+
0x8008         |   | arr[2]
               +---+
                ...

No storage is set aside for a pointer value; arr is the array.  Under most circumstances, the compiler will evaluate the expression arr as something equivalent to &arr[0]; the exceptions to this rule occur when

the array expression is the operand of the sizeof, typeof, typeof_unequal, or unary & operators;
the array expression is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration;

So if you have an array
int arr[N];

and you write
bubbleSort( arr, N );

the compiler generates code equivalent to
bubbleSort( &arr[0], N );

